# Calling sem_open on Solaris as ordinary user

Tags: solaris

This call fails on Solaris with EACCES when ran as ordinary user:

```
sem_open(fileName.c_str(), O_CREAT, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO, 1);
```

When process is started as root, it runs fine. Is this expected behavior?

Environment:

```
$ uname -a
SunOS solaris 5.11 11.0 i86pc i386 i86pc

$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.5.2
```

Answer (score 1):

At the command line try:

```
prctl $$
```

These are the system enforced resource limits your process has.  Note there are

```
process.max-sem-ops
process.max-sem-nsems
project.max-sem-ids
```

These are limits that have a number, if you do not see them (or the limits are already reached) then you have to add them to your account's profile with `projadd` or `projmod` to increase them if your project already exists.

If you cannot do this (no root access) consult with your sysadmin, s/he probably has some reason for not allowing semapahore access.

**Note carefully:**

sempahores are kernel persistent. If you ran your code a bunch of times the sempahores you created are likely still out there.

To see existing semaphores try `ipcs -as`

To remove lingering sempahores that your code should have removed use `ipcrm`

Comment: I have resolved this. OS is in a VM that is occasionally used for testing and just suspended in the meantime, rarely rebooted; reboot seems to have fixed the problem. I do not have an explanation why this was happening, though, because now after I successfully run the code, there is no leftover lingering semaphores. But thanks for your reply, it was helpful.